# Create a pair of keys suitable for DKIM setup using ssh-keygen

Tags: dkim, ssh-keygen

### Question

What is the right way to create a pair of keys suitable for `DKIM` setup using `ssh-keygen`?

Given the corresponding solution with `openssl`:

```bash
# creates a private key
openssl genrsa -out sample.key 1024

# creates a public key 
openssl rsa -in sample.key -pubout -out sample.pub
```

### Story

I was trying to generate keys for `DKIM` using the following procedure:

```bash
# creates a pair of keys: sample & sample.pub
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 1024 -f sample

# coverts the public key into the PEM format
ssh-keygen -f sample.pub -m PEM -e > sample.pem.pub
```

Sample `PEM` public key contents:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAOO3Emm+KdOKKhwlCjLXIE1R76KlWY6xSVfHsjE3uuMcF0BDKhJS2Kg3
WjhdnV2z5XAQDAxknQvx+sxxbsBye6Zc2VnNA9upDVVlNc4I6zl1N75CY7F1Nfbj
wDrpWqGJuBPsousqj79dJ/JM0pzCn71IkEumU2Ck3AULSnT9MLeZAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Constructed `DKIM` record:

```
v=DKIM1; p=MIGJAoGBAOO3Emm+KdOKKhwlCjLXIE1R76KlWY6xSVfHsjE3uuMcF0BDKhJS2Kg3WjhdnV2z5XAQDAxknQvx+sxxbsBye6Zc2VnNA9upDVVlNc4I6zl1N75CY7F1NfbjwDrpWqGJuBPsousqj79dJ/JM0pzCn71IkEumU2Ck3AULSnT9MLeZAgMBAAE=
```

I used https://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck to validate DNS records, which failed me on the provided value with the following message:

> This doesn't seem to be a valid RSA public key: RSA.xs:178: OpenSSL error: wrong tag at blib/lib/Crypt/OpenSSL/RSA.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Crypt/OpenSSL/RSA/new_public_key.al) line 91.

Tried with these versions:

```bash
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
OpenSSH_9.4p1, OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023
```

Luckily, I got the workaround with `openssl` mentioned above. But since `ssh-keygen` [is](https://james.apache.org/howTo/dkim.html) [frequently](https://mailtrap.io/blog/create-dkim-tutorial/#Choose-a-public-and-private-key-generator) [mentioned](https://docs.rackspace.com/docs/create-a-dkim-txt-record#before-you-begin) as a valid tool for `DKIM` keys generation, I’m wondering, what is the way exactly?

Comment: Frequently mentioned? I can't find *any* suggestions that it should work, but multiple people [that point out it won't](https://superuser.com/a/1679367/965644), due to differing formats. So what source suggests you use ssh-keygen?

Comment: Updated the question with a few links, which could lead to such assumption.

Comment: None of your examples actually show how to do it...

Comment: @vidarlo, thanks for the link, seems that I've found the solution with `-m PKCS8 -t rsa`. Need to check few other things..

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what this question is about. It's mentioned possible, but without any working samples at hand.

Comment: Your example mentions 1024. Mind that nowadays, RSA signers [should](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.3.3) use keys of at least 2048 bits.

Comment: @anx, I beleive you meant RFC8301 (SHOULD use at least 2048 bits) not RFC6376 (MUST use at least 1024 bits). Mentioned it in the answer. With respect to possible DNS limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Generate a pair of keys:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -f sample
```

Convert the public key into the `PKCS #8` format:

```bash
ssh-keygen -f sample.pub -m PKCS8 -e > sample.pub.pem
```

### Notes

Internet Standard RFC6376 [specifies](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.6.1) the default key type of DKIM record as RSA and corresponding public key data as base64 encoded ASN.1 DER-encoded RSAPublicKey.

An inspection of the initial public key shows:

```
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 137 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :B758174EDA...bytes...179D51DD18F9
  135:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001
```

An inspection of the solution result:

```bash
openssl asn1parse -i -inform PEM -in sample.pub.pem
```

shows:

```
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 159 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 141 prim:  BIT STRING
```

which is actually the required wrapper around the key. `BIT STRING` at 18 can also be inspected:

```bash
openssl asn1parse -i -inform PEM -in sample.pub.pem -strparse 18
```

```
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 137 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :B758174EDA...same bytes...1DD18F9
  135:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
```

The latest versions of man on `ssh-keygen` [note](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) that using `-m PEM` will cause the key to be stored in the legacy PEM private key format. Which is also [mentioned](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.8) as OpenSSL's PEM format.

The quickly noticeable difference is in header labels. `-m PKCS8` produces:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

while `-m PEM`:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Worth mentioning that Proposed Standard RFC8301 [states](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8301#section-3.2) that:

> Signers MUST use RSA keys of at least 1024 bits for all keys. Signers SHOULD use RSA keys of at least 2048 bits.

While still [recognizing](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8301#section-1) practical limitations to the should-be approach:

> Widely used DNS configuration software places a practical limit on key sizes, because the software only handles a single 256-octet string in a TXT record, and RSA keys significantly longer than 1024 bits don't fit in 256 octets.

So, if applicable, an approach with recommended bit length should be used:

```bash
# generates a pair
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f sample

# converts the public key into the `PKCS #8`
ssh-keygen -f sample.pub -m PKCS8 -e > sample.pub.pem
```